# Endpoints in WCF FileServer

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF File Server and Client that worked perfectly in Localhost, but when I install the server to another computer the client rise the exception when that want's to upload a file. The exception is:

> The Server reject the credentials.

I add a new server's IP (172.18.20.25) in client's config file.

This is my client config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
    <client>
        <endpoint name="FileRepositoryService" 
    address="net.tcp://172.18.20.25:5000" binding="netTcpBinding" 
    contract="FileServer.Services.IFileRepositoryService" 
    bindingConfiguration="customTcpBinding"/>
    </client>

    <bindings>
        <netTcpBinding>
            <binding name="customTcpBinding" 
    maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483648" transferMode="Streamed"/>
        </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
<startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
</startup>
 </configuration>
```

And this is my server's config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
</startup>
<appSettings>
    <add key="RepositoryDirectory" value="storage"/>
</appSettings>
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
        <service name="FileServer.Services.FileRepositoryService">
            <endpoint name="" binding="netTcpBinding"
                address="net.tcp://localhost:5000"
            contract="FileServer.Services.IFileRepositoryService"
                bindingConfiguration="customTcpBinding" />
        </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
        <netTcpBinding>
            <binding name="customTcpBinding" transferMode="Streamed" 
maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483648" />
        </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

As mentioned before when client and server are running on a single machine it worked fine. I read about add a new WSDL endpoint to server, I am not sure about it and I don't know how add it. What is your suggestion ?

Comment: You're using basic `netTcpBinding` which defaults to using the Windows user account for security. So if your "new" client and the "new" server aren't part of the same Windows domain, or the client's PC is running under an account that's not in that Windows domain, it won't work.

Comment: Read about [Programming WCF Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731925.aspx) and see which setup works best for your service

Answer (score 0):

Check if the application you have has read\write access on the server.

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
address="net.tcp://localhost:5000"
```

Change it to

```
net.tcp://172.18.20.25:5000
```

And have a try.

Another suggestion, try set your net.tcp authentication configuration